# Eclipse no puede resolver un import y no me deja debuggear

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

Hola a toda la comunidad!

Esta es mi primera pregunta en el foro, así que intentaré ser preciso:

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con un equipo de desarrollo y soy el único que usa eclipse. El caso es que, desde la implementación de una funcionalidad que hizo uno de mis compañeros, eclipse me avisa de que hay dos fallos relativos a una dependencia que no consigue resolver:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto no les pasa a ninguno de mis compañeros, ya que ellos usan IDEs distintos (VSCode o IntelliJ). Las soluciones que he visto por internet se basan en tocar archivos de configuración de dependencias (en este caso es un proyecto gradle así que sería toquetear el archivo build.gradle), pero esto no es posible en mi caso ya que si modifico algo de ese fichero puedo perjudicar a mis compañeros, además supongo que hay otra manera de solucionarlo desde eclipse porque si sólo me pasa a mí debe ser algo que se ha quedado corrupto.

Por ello invoco a los eruditos de eclipse que haya en el foro a ver si pueden echarme una mano, porque con esos errores no me deja correr la aplicación en modo debug.

Salu2!

Comment: ¿Te da algún error al ejecutar `./gradlew clean build`? Si no es así comprueba tras su ejecución si eclipse sigue mostrando el error

Comment: Hola @PabloLozano gracias por tu respuesta :) he ejecutado el comando y lo único que me saltan son errores en test: {> Task :test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///C:/Users} y los errores en eclipse siguen apareciendo :(